# Reading 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dataset which comprises of the binary data of pixelated 50x50 images. The array shape is `(50, 50, 90245)`. I want to reach 50x50 pixels of each of the 90245 images. How can I slice the array?

Comment: What would be the shape of your expected output array?

Comment: I suppose it should be (50x50) for every 90245

Comment: So basically you have 90245 images that are each 50x50, and you want to get them all into a list? So maybe you want to change the shape to `(90245, 50, 50)`

Comment: Actually, the proposed solution in the answer worked for me. When I tried your way, it gave me different data

Comment: I think you should read the [numpy manual on indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` is the variable storing the image data, and `i` is the index of the image you want to access, then you can do:

```py
data[:,:,i]
```

to get the desired image data.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is the variable storing the image data, and `i` is the index of the image you want to access, then you can do as @BrokenBenchmark suggested. In case you want a `(50,50,1)` 3D array as the output, you could do:

```
data[:,:,i:i+1]
```

to get the image as a 3D array.

Edit1: If you reshaped your `data` matrix to be of shape `(90245,50,50)`, you can get the ith image by doing `data[i,:,:]` or just `data[i]` to get a `(50,50)` image. Similarly, to get a `(1,50,50)` image, you could do `data[i:i+1,:,:]` or just `data[i:i+1]`.

Edit2: To reshape the array, you could use the `swapaxes()` function in `numpy`.